# Download file to user's local appdata directory through .net core C# controller

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two applications (one .net core web app and one windows forms app). What I need in the end is for the web app to download files to the current web user's local directory so that the winforms app can then later read the files while the user doesn't have any network connection.

If I have just a standard download through my C# controller, the user's download folder is obviously chosen by default as the download location. I would like to be able to choose a specific file path (being the user's local appdata directory).

I thought I could just have the web app download the files to the current user's local appdata directory, then the winforms app could naturally access the files from the same place. But, I realize now that getting the local appdata direcotry path through

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

returns the local appdata on our **web server**, not the **client's** local appdata directory as intended.

Is there any way to download the files to the current user's local appdata directory through a .net web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused on what the web server's job is in this scenario.

`What I need in the end is for the web app to download files to the current web user's local directory so that the winforms app can then later read the files while the user doesn't have any network connection.`

You cannot do this; at a minimum, a connection to the server needs to be created from the client first.  Instead, the client app can call out to the web server and ask for a file and put it anywhere the client app wants.  You can directly download bits and save them anywhere the user has access to, but from the win forms app.

`If I have just a standard download through my C# controller, the user's download folder is obviously chosen by default as the download location.`

What does this mean?  Are you showing the user a dialog to pick a file location?  If so, you can skip that and just save where you want.  The point of the file picker is so that the user can select where to save and what name.  Seems like you don't want that.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Executing code like this on the server is exactly as you would expect; the server's information is returned.  There is no point in the server knowing the path on the client app to save.  The client can just download the bits and save where ever.

The short of it is that it is not the webserver's job to push a file onto your machine.  It is the client application's job to request a file and save it.  If you have a default place you want to save (eg, user directory) that's fine, or you can show a file picker or whatever.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. So I would need to just return a byte array from my C# controller and handle the download and download location through the code on the client-side instead of handling everything through the back-end?

Comment: correct.  you can use return File(bytes, filetype, name) from the controller and have the win forms put those bytes anywhere.

Comment: The win forms app is only going to be reading the files. The creating/downloading of the files will ideally be handled through the web application. So I need a common location that the web app can write to and winforms app can read from.

Comment: yep.  however the file is created doesn't matter.  and your controller is not "downloading", it is serving a response to the client.  The client is downloading data.  Web app cannot choose where to write data on a client.  The client has to read data from the web app and save it somewhere.  It can then later reload the data from where it was saved and present to user.